# Exception during populating tableView with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsexception

I got data from JSON and put in to an array. I successfully set cell images with it, now I'm trying to set names.

Apparently, some names are empty, or to be exactly, contain following:

```
"name": null, (pasted from browser JSON viewing)
```

So, when compiler get to this, it throw an exception with following:

```
name is = <null>
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x324586a0
```

I even made some safe checking, but apparently its not working:

```
NSString *nameString = [self.dataDict valueForKey:@"name"];
           if (nameString){
           nameLabel.text = nameString;
           }
```

I don't mind if name would be `null`, but app just crash. How to fix that?

Comment: Write Below Code.
    
    if([nameString length] > 0){
      nameLabel.text = nameString;
    }else{
     nameLabel.text = @"Print Anything you want or pass Blank";
    }

Comment: When you Ask any question first think about solutions of it and do some googling.........

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya your answer is wrong (error is [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13cf6c8). answer any question first think about is your solution correct...